# matplotlib issue: Legend includes both text labels and the line labels. How can I remove the text label from legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Basically: I plotted my line and plotted an x and label at the maximum of the line. When I add the legend, it includes both the line and the label. I only need the line. How can I remove this? I have looked around but can't find a solution to this type of problem.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
##Get intensity for this data set
intensitySubset = intensities[0:20]
##Define colors for three time points
colorVec_Defined_WT = ["lightsteelblue", "royalblue", "darkblue"]
##Define timepointss to graph
timepoints = [0,9,18] 
for i in range(0,len(timepoints)):
    ##Only get data for one of the timepoints
    intensity = intensitySubset[timepoints[i]]
    ##I want to label the max intensity on the graph.
    maxIntensity = np.amax(intensity)
    ##Get index of max intensity value.
    maxIntensityIndex = np.argmax(intensity, axis=0)
    ##Plot the intensity values
    ax.plot(sizes, intensity, color=colorVec_Defined_WT[i])
    ##Add legend
    ax.legend(labels = ["0 min", "", "15 min", "",  "30 min"])
    ##Get the peak intensity, then label it with an x.
    temp, _ = scipy.find_peaks(intensity, height = 0)
    ax.plot(sizes[temp], intensity[temp], "x")
    ##Create a list of labels.
    labels = sizes[temp].tolist()
    labels = ['{:.2f}'.format(x) for x in labels]
    ##Then add labels to graph
    for i in range(0,len(labels)):
        ax.text(sizes[temp][i], intensity[temp][i], labels[i] + " Å", size=10)
    ##Customize graph
    ax.set_title("WT mmCpn Apo Light Scattering") 
    ax.set_xlabel("Particle Diameter Size, Å")
    ax.set_ylabel("Intensity (percent)")
    ax.set_ylim(0,25)
```

[image]

Comment: This needs data. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a complete [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay.

Comment: You could remove the call to `ax.legend()` inside the loop, add a label to `ax.plot(sizes[temp], intensity[temp], "x", label=f"{i}  min")` and add a call to `ax.legend()` (without parameters) after the loop has ended.